# Send text to Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi how can I send received text in a `Program.cs` to a `ListBox` on a `Form1`.

```
if (text == "alerts-")
{
    Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
    string[] text = text.Split('-');

    Form1.listBox1.Items.Add("Recived" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "> " + text);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong??

Comment: Why you are running form in separate thread?

Comment: an object reference is required to access non -static member Form1.listBox1.Items.Add

Comment: `Form1`is the class,not the object. Do this: `Form1 f=new Form1(); Task.Run(() => Application.Run(f)));...f.listBox1.Items.Add("Recived" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "> " + text);`

Comment: Now I need to do something so I do not open a new window every time I send a message --> http://prntscr.com/dzb2yc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the text before you create the form, and since the form requires the text, include it as an argument on the form's constructor.

In the form itself, add the constructor argument:

```
public Form1(string[] text)
{
    // do whatever you need to do with the text on Form1
}
```

Then send it when creating the instance of the form:

```
Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1(text.Split('-'))));
```